# dplyr grouping help, how to select a value from another column based on the min value of another

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame

```
user_id Value webpage
       1   100  google
       1    50  bing
```

I am trying to group by user id and get the mean of "Value" and the value of the webpage where "Value" is the min, in this case "bing"

I have this code where I can get the mean

```
data <- data %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(Value))
```

and I get this result

```
user_id  mean
      1    75
```

how can I get this result

```
user_id  mean  webpage
      1    75     bing
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `data %>% group_by(user_id) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Value), webpage = webpage[which.min(Value)])`?

Comment: thanks, it worked :), do you want to put it as an answer so I can accept it?